# Android Animation-View Animation On Transistion

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-animation

I am using Xamarin to develop an app. I am trying to achieve an Transition Animation Between the Activities such that the exit animation include another animation in which the relative layout move down and Activity exit to right and enters from left.

I tried it with FragmentActivity and as well as Activity. But could not Acheive as I needed. The following is something I tried.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.login);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.loginLoginButton);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout> (Resource.Id.loginFooterLayout);


        button.Click += async (sender, eventargs) => {

            Animation shake = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.outToBottom);
            relativeLayout.StartAnimation(shake);
            shake.FillAfter=true;
            shake.FillEnabled=true;

            shake.AnimationEnd+=delegate {
                StartActivity(typeof(editProfileActivity));
                OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.inFromRight,Resource.Animation.outToLeft);
            };


        };
    }
```

The above code executes such a way that first the relative layout moves down and when the animation is ended the transistion take place. But I want these things to happen at once.

Any kind of help will be appriciated.